# How to disable rygel server

Tags: server, systemd, dlna, upnp, rygel

After clean install of Ubuntu 19.10 I have noticed that there is running `rygel` server:

```bsh
$ sudo netstat --listening -tpn

Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1099/systemd-resolv 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:41127         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1743/rygel
```

It looks like it was turned on by `systemd`:

```bsh
$ pstree
systemd─┬─ModemManager───2*[{ModemManager}]
        ...
        ├─systemd─┬─(sd-pam)
        ...       ...
        │         ├─pulseaudio───3*[{pulseaudio}]
        │         ├─rygel───3*[{rygel}]
```

I can't find service responsible for enabling it. I tried:

```bsh
$ systemctl list-unit-files --no-pager | grep -i rygel
$ systemctl list-unit-files --no-pager | grep -i dlna
$ systemctl list-unit-files --no-pager | grep -i upnp
$ systemctl list-units --no-pager | grep -i rygel
$ systemctl list-units --no-pager | grep -i dlna
$ systemctl list-units --no-pager | grep -i upnp
```

How to disable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the command, at least if you want to remove it completely:

```
sudo apt-get remove rygel
```

This worked for me.